# Best server design for MongoDB based system (low response times needed)

Tags: c#, mongodb, database-design, architecture

I am developing a web service which will serve users all over the world.

The server is based on a C# WCF application hosted on IIS. 
It uses an MsSQL Configuration Database (access time is not important here),
and a MongoDB database which contains all the important data (access time is VERY important here).
Also it serves small images (48px * 48px JPEGs).

Now, for the image hosting I will probably use Amazon's CloudFront CDN hosting (unless you guys have better suggestions).

My issue is maintaining a low access time (ping) to both the Web Application and the MongoDB.

I was thinking to lease 4 servers in Singapore + US + Europe + Middle East to get a low response time.

Each server will hold the Web Application and an instance of MongoDB.
And one server will hold the MsSQL instance.

I need all MongoDB's to be synced (not instantly if its an issue).

What design would you use?

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Low access time is a function of cost vs benefit. First you need to identify, how low is low. Do you need a response time of 100ms overall from the app? or 1s?

Once you do, you map out the different costs.

```
   Total time taken = time for request + //across internet 
processing by web app + request for data + 
preparing the response + response back to client.
```

If your desired latency is 100ms, there is a good chance that it can't be done regardless of how fast your servers are, simple because network traffic might take too long.

You need to analyze your dataset. Querying 1000 documents is different from querying 1 billion docs. You need to calculate how much size the index is taking, and is it in RAM or not. If index is not in RAM, your access is going to be slow.

**Mongodb configuration**

Mongodb can work in a cluster, with automatic syncing (immediate or delayed, this is configurable), and automatic failover (or manual, this is configurable too). It also supports sharding if your dataset is huge, so request is sent to the server that actually contains data.

Similarly, you need to have a look at your app server and figure out how slow/fast components are to get a guaranteed response time.

With the information you have provided, this is about as detailed a response I can give.

**Profile and then optimize**

If 80% of your requests come from middle east, then you ought make it fast for them first. Using the same principal, you need to figure out the slowest components in response time, and improve them. In order to do that, you need to gather the data.

**Clustering**

Setting up a cluster in one continent or across continents, will help you provide redundancy, automatic failover (if configured), and load balancing (depending on how you configure it). If you have alot of data, consider sharding.

Consider going through the docs for [replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/) and [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/).

**Example Server Setup**

Suppose you want to have 10 shards with replication factor of 3 i.e your data is divided across 10 servers and each server really is a replica set of 3 servers (for availability and fail over) i.e each server in the replica set contains duplicate data.

here notation s1p1 means, shard1 - primary 1 and s1s1 is shard 1 secondary 1 and so on

```
s1p1 s2p1 ...  s10p1
s1s1 s2s1  ... s10s1
s1s2 s2s2  ... s10s2
```

Shards 1-10 divide the data, where each shard approximately keeps 1/10 of total. Each shard comprises of a replica set with a primary and 2 secondaries. You can increase this if you need more redundancy. Try to keep it to odd, so during elections there is a tie breaker. If you want to have only 2 copies of the data, then you can also introduce an "Arbiter" to break the tie.

You could analyze your queries, and choose a shard key so that they go to the closest server, or the server which serves the region. You'll most likely have to do some sort of analysis to optimize this bit.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the comment. I am aware of response time issues, but my questions is, what design should I implement to the MongoDB. Should I hold one instance? Or an Instance in every continent to ensure low ping.

Comment: first you'll need to figure out what the desired response time is. Then figure out, how much time database is consuming. If database is consuming 10% and 90% is elsewhere, perhaps there is another dragon to slay. But to answer your question, if you have one in every continent, it will certainly help, however the question becomes, is it needed? (is there a business case? if so, go for it). Ideally, you'll want to have a cluster (spread across continents if need be) which can handle traffic, provide automatic fail over, and redundancy. Look to shard if need be.

Comment: It is needed because I have to maintain low ping rates, less than 100ms. My main issue is the DB location. Should I shard? replicate? Thanks

Comment: Sharding is useful especially for reads (and writes if rebalancing is not required immediately). If data is well distributed, ideally, queries will hit few shards, hence your reponse will be better. Replication is to mitigate against slow networks, or server problems or other instances where a server might be unavailable, and you want a backup/secondary available to read data from (and it can potentially become the new primary so you can write to it too)

Comment: depending on size of data, you probably want to do both. Replication certainly.